# Facebook og:image gives different URL + wrong image

Tags: image, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I've been having this problem for some days now and spend 2 hours debugging a simple meta tag without result.
The problem I'm facing is that the facebook debugger provides me with a whole different url from cloudfront and sets wrong meta image.

[The url](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fyummygum.com%2Fcareers%2Fstagiair-visual-designer%2F)

[The Image it should show](https://yummygum.com/assets/img/meta/meta-img-careers-stagiair-visual-designer-new.png)

I also made a thread on facebook.com: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/807177749469671/

Comment: Start by specifying og:url correctly ... Right now you are telling Facebook that it should go to `https://yummygum.com/` to fetch the meta data for this, and so that’s what it does.

Comment: I defined it correctly see: 
https://gist.github.com/noudadrichem/808eca20ae7139f72863222ed89c0338

It just scrapes wrong...

Answer (score 0):

The [object debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fyummygum.com%2Fcareers%2Fstagiair-visual-designer%2F) from Facebook for your given URL mentions that some redirects are occurring on the page, it's also mentioning when these redirections occur. It can either be an HTTP direction, meta-tag with og:url property or a link tag. Your page does contain one of these tags, on line 91 to be specific;

```
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//yummygum.com">
```

This redirection is why Facebook is trying to load an image with the name "meta-img.png" since this is the og:image the homepage is referring to. Try to remove that link redirection and see if it's loading the right image.